# Restoring the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application has one activity and 5 fragments. When user clicks on tab "Fragment1", it loads the data from remote place and upload it on ListView. "Fragment2" also doing same job. But when user clicks back on "Fragment1" it again starts loading, instead of loading

> How can I restore the fragment from last loaded state?

Comment: what do you mean by starts loading instead of loading?? Please check your question once

Comment: it again starts loading, instead of loading  - > reloading instead of reusing? .  Your frag manager never does that if you don't tell it to reload so, check (and post?) your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you post some code. Meanwhile, my sneaky suspicion is that instead of reusing the same instance, your `FragmentPagerAdapter` is creating a new instance every time its `getItem()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a check in OnStart() of the fragment.

```
  if(listView has Content || is not null)
      {
              //get the data from remote 
      }
  else
      {
             //don;t do anything
      }
```